# How do you "tail" the output of a command in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

What I mean by tail is capture the commands output while it's running instead of just getting it at the end of it's execution. For example, if you do a long running command it will look something like this:

```
# Run command
puts `ey deploy`
# Nothing happening for a while....
# ...
# Now see all of the output at once.
```

What I'd like to do is run a command through ruby and see it's output as it's happening.

Comment: Put the entire command (with `tail`) in the backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks will wait for the entire command to complete then return it's output as a single string, as you've observed. To get the output as it's produced, try [`Open3::popen2e`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2e)

Here's an example using a bash loop which sleeps for a second between each line to demonstrate the incremental streaming nature of this interface:

```
require 'open3'

CMD = %{for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done}

Open3.popen2e('bash', '-c', CMD) do |i,oe,t|
  oe.each { |line| puts line }
end
```